# Adding data to and querying a partitioned BigQuery table

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-bigquery

In BigQuery I'm making a partitioned data table (partitioned by hour) and while data are going into it, it doesn't appear that the results have a `_PARTITIONTIME` pseudocolumn; when I do

```
SELECT
  _PARTITIONTIME AS pt,
  *
FROM
  [my_dataset.my_partitioned_table]
LIMIT
  1000
```

I get all the regular columns of my table, but `_PARTITIONTIME` is null for every entry. The data are being sent in from a call to the Go BigQuery API the same way they were when I was sending the data to an unpartitioned table, and they're queried from the BigQuery console. Would the data be more likely to be being inserted wrong or queried wrong?

Comment: what exactly you mean by `partitioned by hour`? currently only DAY is supported as a partitioning type!

Comment: That would explain a lot. Where did you see this in the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently only DAY is supported as a partitioning type!

See more details in [timePartitioning](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#timePartitioning) property

And see more about [Partitioned Tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables) in general